# I have a server running Windows 2008 R2 Core and it needs to hosts either SVN or GIT

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008-r2, git, windows-server-core

The server allocated for our cross platform projects (both Mac & PC) source repository is running Win2008R2 Core. We're really happy with its stability and we aren't interested in moving over to non-core. We need to get either SVN or GIT installed on the aforementioned box in the shortest amount of steps.

We know the advantages/disadvantages of both systems. That being said, we don't care which one we use, we're just are looking for the path of least resistance on setting up a repository on a machine running R2 core.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work fine for you:

- http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jason_meridth/archive/2009/06/01/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-1.aspx